# how I can save output record separately in different rows by processing different csv files using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

```
folder_name = 'Dataset_test'
file_type = 'csv'
seperator =','
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=seperator) for f in glob.glob(folder_name + "/*."+file_type)],ignore_index=True)
```

Now all csv reads but made one dataframe and output is saved as record i want in different records like 2 files load than 2 records should create.

Comment: would you mind adding the desired output schema?

Comment: its like read file from folder and run loop on it and run specific code then append result and loop end and than again read other file and same process go

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't understand the problem! Do you want to read files from several directories, process them and save them in separate files?
You merged all  `file_type` files presented in `folder_name` to one big file, now what do you want to do with it?